# Como aplicar !important do CSS via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou tentando aplicar um estilo ao meu elemento e definir a importância dele, desta maneira:

```css
$('div').css('height','50px!important');
```

Porém, não funciona, qual seria a maneira correta?

Comment: Acho que não deveria ser necessário usar o `!important` se você está manipulando o elemento diretamente, pois o estilo do próprio elemento tem precedência sobre as outras definições.

Comment: Claro, mas e se caso você queria sobrescrever uma atribuição que já esteja em uma folha de estilo padrão?

Comment: caso exista uma regra em uma folha de estilo que ja tenha o !important isso é útil, porém é uma boa observação...

Comment: O valor que você setar no estilo do elemento deve sobrescrever a definição da folha de estilo padrão. Posso não estar entendendo o problema, você pode criar um jsfiddle demonstrando o problema?

Comment: Se existe uma regra em um arquivo css que já tenha uma propriedade com o !important, então o que eu determinar no atributo style do elemento, não irá sobrescrever, por isso nele tem que ter o !important também, simples assim...

Comment: Experimenta: $('.prodMenor:eq(6)').css({'margin-right':'0 !important'});

Comment: Não funcionou também, mas pensei em uma solução alternativa. Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [Por que as propriedades CSS com atributo !important não funcionam no método .css()?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6590/por-que-as-propriedades-css-com-atributo-important-n%C3%A3o-funcionam-no-m%C3%A9todo-css)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Não está funcionando pois o Jquery não reconhece a declaração !important.
De maneira simples, você pode fazer dessa forma:

```css
$('div').attr('style', 'width: 50px!important');
```

Isso deve solucionar, porém ira sobrescrever os estilos anteriores que estiverem setados. Para que isso não ocorra, isso ira manter os estilos anteriores e adicionar novos:

```css
$('#elem').attr('style', function(i,s) { return s + 'width: 100px !important;' });
```

Answer (score 15):

A melhor maneira de aplicar regras de CSS é sempre usando classes.

Assim o melhor é defenir no CSS uma classe

```css
.minhaClasse {
    width: 50px!important
}
```

e adicionar a classe com:

```js
$('#elem').addClass('minhaClasse');
```

Para além dessa maneira ideal, e tendo em conta que jQuery é javascript pode ser melhor, neste caso usar o style e nomeadamente o setProperty que tem um [parametro para a importância](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration).

**Assim, poderia usar:**

```js
$('#elem')[0].style.setProperty('width', '50px', 'important');
```

**ou**

```js
document.getElementById('elem').style.setProperty('width', '50px', 'important');
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wvu8S/)

Comment: Apesar do Denis ter respondido "com mais jQuery",  gostei da dica Javascript do `setProperty`, acho que poucos programadores se lembram desse terceiro parâmetro -- que, alias [é cross-browser](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdpsdnb.php). Fica a pergunta "Por que [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) não oferece esse flag?"

Answer (score 10):

Você pode usar desta forma:

```
$(".prodMenor:eq(6)").css("cssText", "margin-right: 0 !important");
```

> Cuidado: neste caso você precisa setar todas as propriedades desejadas.

Veja mais em http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066 <sup>(en)</sup>

Se quiser uma função para aplicar o `!important` separadamente, tem uma **[aqui](http://pritomkumar.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/how-can-i-add-css-with-important-only.html)**.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) do jQuery:

```
$('.prodMenor:eq(6)').attr('style','margin-right: 0 !important');
```

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/f05Lg8qs/)

Comment: boa garouuuuto!

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de criar uma função que faz exatamente o que a pergunta pede:

```
// jquery-css-important.js v1
jQuery.fn.extend({
    cssImportant: function(key, val) {
        let $div = $('<div>');
        $div.css(key, val);
        let style = $div.attr('style');
        $div.remove();
        let $this = $(this);
        if (style) {
            $this.css(key, val);
            let oldStyle = $this.attr('style');
            $this.attr('style', oldStyle.replace(style, style.replace(';', '!important;')));
        };
        return $this;
    }
});
```

As outras respostas não contemplam exatamente o que foi pedido.
O uso de classes é o melhor dos mundos porque é o jeito certo, mas não resolve todos os casos como, por exemplo, um item já ter !important dentro do style.
Usar attr é ruim porque mexe no atributo inteiro o que significa descartar outras propriedades. Adicionar no fim do atributo style também é ruim pois sem uma verificação via expressão regular ou algo parecido você pode acabar com duas propriedades iguais poluindo o código:

```
<div style="width: 100px; width: 110px!important;"></div>
```

O meu código utiliza o próprio jQuery para verificar se há duplicações de css no atributo style e então incrementa com !important. Desta maneira o uso é tão simples quanto o $.css normal e o resto do código continua funcionando normalmente.

O uso é simples:

```
$('div').cssImportant('margin', '10px');
```

Não fiz suporte para objetos então para adicionar mais de um item é necessário mais de uma linha.