# Por que setar uma propriedade CSS com o atributo !important não funciona no método .css()?

Tags: jquery, css

Gostaria de saber o motivo real da incapacidade que a função [jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) possui, que seria o fato de que ao utilizar o atributo `!important` em qualquer propriedade CSS atribuída, o mesmo não é adicionado.

Também gostaria de saber se há algum meio funcional de utilizar o atributo `!important` **no método `.css()`**

**Obs:** Estou falando somente e exclusivamente, do método `.css()` e não de qualquer outro método existente para atribuir CSS.

Comment: Ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1695/como-aplicar-important-do-css-via-jquery

Comment: Possível duplicata com com o link que o @GabrielSantos citou?

Comment: Eu já vi todas estas questões que falam sobre `!important` mas nenhuma delas esclarece minha dúvida.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Funciona sim! Só que com uma variante:

```
.css("cssText", "color: green !important;")
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bHm7/)

Para adicionar mais propriedades é só acrescentar [**na mesma string**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bHm7/3/):

```
.css("cssText", "color: green !important; font-size:50px;")
                 ^                        ^
```

Esta variante é a unica maneira usando `.css()` como a pergunta pede. Note que desta maneira o CSS é `reiniciado`, assim todo o CSS que tenha sido defenido fora do stylesheet [**perde-se**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bHm7/2/), conforme referíu e bem o [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6620/129).

Inclusíve CSS defenido no elemento como `<div style="font-style:italic;">`.

A maneira correcta é usando javascript como referí [**noutra pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1698/129), usando: `setProperty('color', 'green ', 'important');`

Comment: CARA, realmente funciona!! Sergio você é o salvador da pátria \o\

Comment: Isso parece trapaça :)

Comment: Aha! É mesmo trapaça! Isso sobrescreve o objeto style inteiro. http://jsfiddle.net/8bHm7/1/

Comment: @bfavaretto, verdade, talvez mesmo a evitar pois é um método bem "cego". Mas pode ser útil se fôr preciso fazer um reset ao style no caso de se querer __[voltar ao estado inicial](http://jsfiddle.net/8bHm7/4/)__.

Answer (score 7):

O "motivo real", eu não sei dizer, teríamos de perguntar ao John Resig, criador do jQuery. É possível que tenha a ver com compatibilidade entre browsers, performance, ou com própria história da biblioteca (foi implementada de tal maneira que seria custoso mudar agora). Se eu fosse chutar, chutaria como principal motivo *compatibilidade* – adivinha com qual browser?

O que posso explicar é *como* isso realmente funciona no jQuery. Mas antes:

#### Como definir um estilo `!important` com JavaScript puro?

No browser em que estou agora (Chrome), somente três maneiras funcionam:

```
el.setAttribute('style', 'color: green !important');
// ou
el.style.cssText = 'color: green !important';
// ou
el.style.setProperty('color', 'green', 'important');

// NÃO FUNCIONAM:
// el.style.color = 'green !important';
// el.style['color'] = 'green !important';
// el.style = 'color: green !important';
```

A primeira opção sobrescreve o *atributo* `style` do elemento, como se você tivesse definido `style="..."` no próprio HTML. Isso também instrui o browser a reprocessar os estilo daquele elemento.

A segunda e a terceira opções funcionam modificando uma propriedade ou chamando um método do objeto style, que que é um objeto do tipo `CSSStyleDeclaration`. Essa interface foi [definida na especificação CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration) (hoje faz parte dos [rascunhos do CSSOM](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface)). Aliás, o IE só dá suporte a isso [a partir da versão 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975068(v=vs.85).aspx), o que me faz suspeitar de *compatibilidade* como um grande motivo para o jQuery não suportar atribuição de `!important`.

A segunda opção, `el.style.cssText`, é equivalente à primeira, e sobrescreve todo o `style` do elemento. A terceira opção, `el.style.setProperty`, é mais seletiva, e opera em cima de uma propriedade específica do objeto `style`, cujo nome deve ser passado como primeiro argumento. É a maneira "correta" (do ponto de vista da especificação) de se definir o `!important`, visto que possui um terceiro parâmetro *priority* exatamente para isso.

#### E como o `.css` do jQuery realmente funciona?

Quando você chama `$('seletor').css('color', 'green')`, o jQuery primeiro faz um loop em todos os elementos que casam com o seletor. Neste caso em que `.css` é invocado como *setter*, ele chama o método interno [`jQuery.style`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L243) para cada elemento, passando o elemento como primeiro parâmetro, a propriedade como o segundo, e o valor como o terceiro. Esse método faz algumas normalizações (como acrescentar `px` ao valor se for numérico), e no final faz algo equivalente a isto:

```
el.style[prop] = value;
```

Repare que esse é um dos formatos que não funcionam para definir `!important`. E é por isso que não adianta passar `!important` no valor usado com `.css`. Isso também explica por que a sugestão do Sergio funciona: `.css("cssText", "color: green !important;")` equivale a `el.style['cssText'] = 'color: green !important;'`, que é a variação da segunda versão JS puro que mencionei (mas acessando a propriedade com colchetes em vez de ponto).

Comment: Boa explicação! `+1`

Comment: Surpreendente, você de fato sempre com explicações muito boas e detalhadas, era realmente o que eu queria saber, além de você dar as soluções que funcionam e as que não funcionam, você ainda disse o motivo de tudo isso. Sem palavras, +1

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal!